# Xcode/iOS: Launchscreen.storyboard can only be edited in Objective-C?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

When I create a new iOS project in Xcode with its language set to Swift, I get two `playgrounds` from the single-view template. For some reason, when I open `Main.storyboard` using the `Assistant` editor, I can edit it in Swift, but when I do the same for `LaunchScreen.storyboard` it seems to open a file in Objective-C.

Why is that? Can `LaunchScreen.storyboard` not be edited in Swift or am I opening the wrong file when I select `LaunchScreen.storyboard` and open it with `Editor -> Assistant`?

Comment: Storyboards don't have a language. The launch screen storyboard can't be linked to code anyway, so it doesn't matter what the assistant editor shows; there is no need to open the assistant editor for the launch storyboard

Comment: Ah thank you, that's what I meant, link it to code. So, what kind of strategy can one use to check if the app is in dark-mode and adjust background color, text color, and so forth based on that check?

Comment: The launch storyboard is shown before any code runs. The first code you get to execute is in your app delegate.  You can use adaptive colours on iOS 13 for dark mode https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/214/